# Recursive list in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion

I've been trying to get a recursive list of XSLT rows working -- each item has a numeric ID and an optional Parent Item ID that should be used to identify the item it could go under.

Here's my input XML (formatted thanks to SharePoint):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="parentchild.xslt"?>
<Rows>
    <Row>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <Title>Top Item 1</Title>
        <Parent></Parent>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <Title>Top Item 2</Title>
        <Parent></Parent>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <Title>Child 1 for top item 1</Title>
        <Parent>1</Parent>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <Title>Child 2 for top item 1</Title>
        <Parent>1</Parent>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <Title>Grandchild 1 for top item 1</Title>
        <Parent>3</Parent>
    </Row>
</Rows>
```

This is a mockup of my expected result:

[image: expected result]

And this is my actual result: Each of the top-level items becomes a child of the other top-level items. The **real** children (and they are legion) are nowhere to be found.

[image: All the top level items become children... of themselves.]

My best guess is that I'm using Current wrong, or traversing wrong... I am *not* an XSLT guru by any means.

Comment: Show the input XML, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: ... as code, not as pictures.

Comment: Easier said than done, michael.hor257k, unless there is a way to do this in SharePoint that I am missing. I am attempting to reproduce this now in 100% local code, so constructive criticism or suggestions on seeing raw XML in SharePoint would be helpful, not an unhelpful complaint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Maybe I shouldn't have used so many `@` signs in there.
2. `//Rows` fixed things for child items.

I still have no idea how this'll go back into SharePoint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:template match='/'>
    <ul>    
        <xsl:apply-templates select='Rows/Row[Parent=""]' />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match='Row'>
    <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="Title" />
        <br/>Child items:
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//Rows/Row[Parent=current()/ID]" />
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result:

[image: a properly cascading list]

Answer (score 1):

Well, every time you process a Row, you generate an `<li><ul>XXX</ul></li>` structure, and your recursive call populates XXX, so clearly each row is going to generate another level (or two) of nesting. I can't tell you how to fix that since I don't understand your pictures.

Comment: But why is it only recursively calling things with no parent, versus using the current ID of a row to check for other rows with the current ID as a parent ID?

Comment: I'm sure there was some code here when I wrote my answer, but I don't see any now. How can I tell why your code is wrong with no code to look at?